# JsonObject/JsonValue is not working to parse JSON in Windows Phone 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I'm facing issue while parsing JSON in windows phone 8. I've a json string like

```
{"ids":{"internal":[{"type":"ABCD","id":"7BCDCA0676CC8E2F5","time":19376,"asV":"AP_33160"}
                     ,{"type":"ADFP","id":"A2D3D22A6458BC2B","time":19376,"asV":"AP_420TETA"}
                     ]
            },
 "err":6000,
 "msg":"No Msg",
 "timeTL":87600
}
```

I want to have values like:

```
string strIds= "{"internal":[{"type":"ABCD","id":"7BCDCA0676CC8E2F5","time":19376,"asV":"AP_33160"},{"type":"ADFP","id":"A2D3D22A6458BC2B","time":19376,"asV":"AP_420TETA"}]}" ;


int err= 6000;
string message= "msg";
int timeTL=87600;
```

I'm able to get the required results on Windows 8 using JsonValue but it is not supported on Windows Phone 8. The major problem is the content of "internal" is not fixed and I want to save the complete value of "ids" into a string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your Json data using **Newtonsoft.Json**. this library is available On Nuget.org. 
Add this to yuor project by going to Tools->Libiya Package Manager ->Packae manager console
and type **Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json**

Create class as follows. By using json string and http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class RootObject
{
    //public Ids ids { get; set; } 
    public object ids { get; set; } //use type object for id 
    public int err { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public int timeTL { get; set; }
}


results = reader.ReadToEnd();
then using newtonsoft.json
RootObject root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(results, new JsonSerializerSettings
                    {
                        NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
                        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full
                    });
```

You can get Id's value by using

```
string str= root.ids.Tostring();
```

Hope this works